# Is there a way to show in the query log on which file or class the query was executed on?

Tags: debugging, cakephp

I currently have a reasonably big application running on cakephp, some pages generate quite a few queries to the database. Some queries are called in current controller, but others maybe called on a function on a remote model, also while using containable behavior with many models related it's becoming quite difficult to know from where certain query came from to optimize it.

I search on the docs but there's nothing about configuring the query log, also installed the debugkit but haven't found any functionality capable of doing that.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate your sql connection in a PHP class, and make your query method log extra information. Another method is to add comments to the SQL query itself "--" characters denote a comment, and manually add the current PHP file path.

Comment: if I where using plain php I would follow your advice, but I don't see a way of doing it without touching the Cakephp core classes.